# localhost:3000/topics/index and localhost:3000/topics/show BOTH route to same show.html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For some reason both these URLS are routing to the same file when they shouldn't be, another thing that I noticed when typing in an invalid url such as localhost:3000/topics/inexjojvnsjg it just stays on the same page.

here is what my rails console is telling me when I try to access the url
`localhost:3000/topics/index`

```
Started GET "/topics/index" for ::1 at 2015-02-06 17:33:07 -0700
Processing by TopicsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}
Rendered topics/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =$1   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 98ms (Views: 96.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

here is my routes file....

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users
get 'welcome/index'
get 'welcome/about'

# get "topics/index"
# get "topics/show"
# get "topics/new"
# get "topics/edit"
#for some reason, using resources:topics, index and show both route to  show
resources :topics

root to: 'welcome#index'

post :incoming, to: 'incoming#create'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the key info:

```
Started GET "/topics/index" for ::1 at 2015-02-06 17:33:07 -0700
Processing by TopicsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}
```

The `:index` url for a TopicsController is "/topics".

The `:show` url for a TopicsController is "/topics/:id" or "/topics/1", where the last part of the url gets associated to the `params[:id]`. With the url "/topics/1" the `:id` = 1.

So when you go to the url "/topics/index" you are going to the `:show` action because of the "index" part of the url. You are just setting the `:id` to "index" instead of a Integer `:id`. You can see that in the output you pasted here:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}
```

TLDR: "/topics/index" is a route the will pass the Rails router but is an invalid route, because the `:id` is a String "index".

Comment: @BartDangus, don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is correct!